# Calculate percentage of increase/decrease of time series data table always with respect to first row/day

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

I have a data table in `R`, which can look like the following one:

```
set.seed(123)
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-10-16'), by = '1 day', length.out = 8),
                      'Power' = rnorm(8, 30, 1), 'Gas' = rnorm(8, 10, 1),
                      'CO2' = rnorm(8, 40, 1), check.names = FALSE)
```

`dt.data` is just a counterexample. The `date` range can always differ.

I would like to calculate the percentage increase or decrease per day for each product/column (Power, Gas, ...) depending on the first start day (here `2020-10-16`) and save it in a new data table. I assume that the value on October 16 is `0%`. I need this calculation for a plot that should look something like this:

[image]

Here you can see that we are assuming `0%` on October 16 and then always calculate/plot the daily deviation (in `%`) in relation to the start date.

How can I create such an data table, where the daily deviation in `%` is listed for each product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
dt.data %>% mutate(across(Power:CO2, ~(. - first(.))/first(.)))
```

In `data.table` you can do this with `.SDcols`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt.data)
cols <- c('Power', 'Gas', 'CO2')

dt.data[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - first(x))/first(x)), 
          .SDcols = cols]

dt.data
#         date       Power        Gas          CO2
#1: 2020-10-16  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.000000000
#2: 2020-10-17  0.01121955 0.02589789 -0.060854283
#3: 2020-10-18  0.07198431 0.20518678  0.005025092
#4: 2020-10-19  0.02143323 0.11238593 -0.023967738
#5: 2020-10-20  0.02342984 0.11678376 -0.038660674
#6: 2020-10-21  0.07729543 0.08563545 -0.017675639
#7: 2020-10-22  0.03469458 0.01406739 -0.037628045
#8: 2020-10-23 -0.02393332 0.26562084 -0.030291526
```

Comment: Ronak, as i have said previously your answers always fascinate me.  Where can I learn this `tilde` syntax? It eludes me always at least as of now?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me only the data table version does what I need. With the ```dplyr```-package there is no change.

Comment: @AnilGoyal That is A purrr-style lambda function similar to anonymous function.

Comment: @Michi You need to assign the data back in `dplyr` version. `dt.data <- dt.data %>% mutate...`

Answer (score 1):

Just another option to calculate percentage changes with rebasing:

```
dt.data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) c(0, cumprod(exp(diff(log(x)))) - 1)), .SDcols=Power:CO2]
```

It is quite fun if you peel it layer by layer to see what it is doing.

Or

```
dt.data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) cumprod(x / shift(x, fill=x[1L])) - 1), .SDcols=Power:CO2]
```